# Hash Error when trying to get Document Signed

Tags: cosign-api

When I try to send a document and signee over SOAP to CoSign in order to append the signature, I'm getting the following error:

```
      <ResultMajor>urn:oasis:names:tc:dss:1.0:resultmajor:ResponderError</ResultMajor>
      <ResultMinor>urn:oasis:names:tc:dss:1.0:resultminor:GeneralError</ResultMinor>
      <ResultMessage lang="en">Failed create and sign err 90030389</ResultMessage>
```

I know it's a very generic error, but I'm unsure what to do next.  Any ideas? I've been told the username and password are correct, and are working when using the CoSign client. (I've also truncated some of the binary)

My soap request is:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <ns1:DssSign xmlns:ns1="http://arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/">
            <ns2:SignRequest xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:tc:dss:1.0:core:schema" RequestID="DummyRequestId">
                <ns2:OptionalInputs>
                    <ns2:ClaimedIdentity NameQualifier=" ">
                        <ns2:Name>UserName</ns2:Name>
                        <ns2:SupportingInfo>
                            <ns3:LogonPassword xmlns:ns3="http://arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0">Password</ns3:LogonPassword>
                        </ns2:SupportingInfo>
                    </ns2:ClaimedIdentity>
                    <ns2:SignatureType>http://arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0/signature-field-create-sign</ns2:SignatureType>
                    <ns3:SAPISigFieldSettings xmlns:ns3="http://arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0" Name="SigField" DependencyMode="Independent" SignatureType="Digital" Page="1" X="366" Y="705" Height="58" Width="182" EmptyFieldLabel="" Invisible="false"/>
                    <ns3:ReturnPDFTailOnly xmlns:ns3="http://arx.com/SAPIWS/DSS/1.0">true</ns3:ReturnPDFTailOnly>
                </ns2:OptionalInputs>
                <ns2:InputDocuments>
                    <ns2:Document>
                        <ns2:Base64Data MimeType="application/pdf">JVBERi0xLjQKJaqrrK0KNCAwI0YK</ns2:Base64Data>
                    </ns2:Document>
                </ns2:InputDocuments>
            </ns2:SignRequest>
        </ns1:DssSign>
    </Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: please update the above SOAP request with the 'envelope' element that is currently missing. The content inside the 'Body' element looks fine.

Comment: I've edited the post to include the envelope - there's nothing too special going on there.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `S` namespace to the `Body` element - `<S:Body>...</S:Body>`